# Sending photos without compression, telegrambot file

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, send, telebot

How do I send a photo to chat without compression, as a file. When I implement it with the current method, the file is sent as a document without an extension.

```
bot = TeleBot("API")

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def send(message):
    with open("5.jpg", "rb") as file:
        f = file.read()
    bot.send_document(message.chat.id, document=f)

bot.polling(True)
```

Answer (score 2):

When you do

```
f = file.read()
```

Combined with `document=f`, Telegram will receive the *content* of the file.

---

To send the file with the original filenamem, pass the `file` variable from `open()`:

```py
with open("/tmp/ccatt.jpeg", "rb") as file:
    bot.send_document(123456789, document=file)
```

[image]